# Doubt in a solved example from Quantum Mechanics: Concepts and Applications by Nouredine Zettili

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Question **3.7 b)** from *Quantum Mechanics: Concepts and Applications* by Nouredine Zettili, on page no. **188** (solved examples) - I understand all the solutions mentioned therein but can't figure out why does the following solution give the wrong answer (What am I missing?)? -
$< \psi _0 | \hat {H} | \psi _0 > = < E_3 \phi _3 + E_2 \phi _2 + E_1 \phi _1 | \hat {H} | E_1 \phi _1 + E_2 \phi _2 + E_3 \phi _3 > = < E_3 \phi _3 + E_2 \phi _2 + E_1 \phi _1 | \hat {H} | E_1 \phi _1 > + < E_3 \phi _3 + E_2 \phi _2 + E_1 \phi _1 | \hat {H} | E_2 \phi _2 > + < E_3 \phi _3 + E_2 \phi _2 + E_1 \phi _1 | \hat {H} | E_3 \phi _3 > $
$ = E_1 ^2 + E_2 ^2 + E_3 ^2 = 3 \epsilon ^2 $

Comment: As I recall, you can only apply $\hat{H}$ to the bra or the ket but not both otherwise you are calculating $\hat{H^2}$.

Comment: @R.Romero I have applied $\hat {H} $ only to the ket here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make so mess, but I'll do calculation step by step if you don't mind :

First, let's write the state $|\psi_0\rangle$ in the eigenbasis of the Hamiltonian.
$$|\psi_0\rangle=c_1|\phi_1\rangle+c_2|\phi_2\rangle+c_3|\phi_3\rangle$$
Given the matrix , I assume that you can find eigen vector and eigen values of Hamiltonian. The coefficients can be found with dotting with the basis vectors so that I also assume, you have no problem with this.

Next step is to find $\langle \hat{H}\rangle$. First we do the following
$$\hat{H}|\psi_0\rangle=c_1\hat{H}||\phi_1\rangle+ c_2\hat{H}||\phi_2\rangle+c_3\hat{H}||\phi_3\rangle$$

We denote eigen values of Hamiltonian by $E_i$ that's the fair notation.
$$\hat{H}|\psi_0\rangle=c_1E_1|\phi_1\rangle+ c_2E_2|\phi_2\rangle+c_3E_3|\phi_3\rangle$$

$$\langle\psi_0|\hat{H}|\psi_0\rangle=c_1^2E_1+c_2^2E_2+c_3^2E_3$$
From here It's easy to  see what's your fault. (You didn't include the eigenvalue of Hamiltonian when act it on the eigenbasis etc.)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I don't know which edition mine is (I'm working through a xeroxed copy of the book). But the solved example I'm stuck on is the one right after the one you just solved. Thanks

Comment: Can you put, at least one sentence of the problem on your question?

Comment: Q) "Consider a physical system whose Hamiltonian $H$ and initial state $|\psi _0>$ are given by"  - matrices for each one are given. b) Calculate $<\hat {H}>$, the expectation value of the Hamiltonian. it's part b) that I'm stuck at.

Comment: Please look at the above solution. Best wishes.

Comment: got it (saw my mistake), thanks a lot!